# Do I have a pop-up virus?

Tags: malware

I have a mac desktop computer about 1 year old, using current OSX... or maybe one version behind the current one.

My Yahoo account was hijacked a few weeks ago for the first time in 12 years. (It happened while VMWare was open, but I don't know if that was the cause). I changed the password and things seem to have calmed down.

But I continue to get a popup alert box asking for my yahoo password. It has the yahoo logo and says Please enter the password for yahoo account -------@yahoo.com (my email address) I don't ever fill it out with my password, but it goes away when I click either CANCEL or OK. It comes back every few minutes and has continued to do so for weeks.

Here's the thing: 
It still happens when my browser is closed. 
It still happens even when my WIFI is disconnected!

That's why I think it's a virus, because it keeps popping up even when the internet connection is off. So that means it's in my computer itself, right?

Anyone else heard of this?
Anyone know what to do about it?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm hoping for a more detailed answer about whether or not this is a known virus or viral appearance, and if there is something specific I can do about it.

Comment: You are running OS X unless you ran a fake installer you are not infected. A fake extension is another story which is why deleting the profile will help.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. What is a fake extension? What do you mean by "the profile" in this case?

Comment: A fake extension is an extension you have installed that does not actually do what it claims it does.  The profile is the Chrome profile that should be deleted at this point to wipe all extensions installed.

Comment: I still don't understand... I'm using Safari, not Chrome, but I don't think I've ever made a Safari profile. Can I wipe all extensions from Safari? How do I do that? How will it affect things I'm used to using?

Comment: I don't know where I got Chrome from but my advice is the same but if it's happening while Safari is closed the only real solution is a wipe from orbit approach

Answer (score 2):

It looks as though the Mail application is putting up the password request, perhaps you didn't change its preferences to your new one?

Comment: No... I mean, it seems like Yahoo is putting up the password request, but it pops up even when yahoo account is closed, and even when the browser is closed.

Comment: @Evan Not the browser, an email application on your computer like ThunderBird or Outlook